# Is there an app, website, or any way to search all tagged Facebook or Instagram photos of someone?

Tags: facebook, search, tags, tagging, instagram

I would like to find a way to search all tagged Facebook or Instagram photos of someone?

I have found many ways to search hashtags and topics but that is not what I'm trying to do. I want to search and display all photos tagged with usernames/handles.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been building a tool that allows you to search yours and your friends' Facebook photos. Youa can find it here: http://www.phemories.com